# Kubernetes: Tasks that need to be done once per cluster or per statefulset or replicaset

Tags: kubernetes

So i heard about `initConainers` which allow you to do pre-app-container initialization. However, i want initialization which are done either at the cluster level or statefulset, or even the whole pod.

For instance, I want to perform a one time hadoop namenode format on my persistent volumes and be done with that. After that is done my namenode statefulset and my datanode replicasets can proceed each time

Does `kubernetes` have anything to accommodate this?

How about its Extensions?

Comment: Can you expand on your requirements a bit more? Maybe give an example of the flow of execution you expect for each type?  [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) are used to manage ad hoc executions but they are not going to execute in an existing pod, or be tightly bound to the startup of something like a statefulset.

Comment: Just gave one example. I wasn't aware of jobs. That could be something that could be used along an initContainer in the main deployments.

Comment: You might need to orchestrate a Job with the Deployment/Statefulset. [`helm`](http://helm.sh/) has pre and post [hooks](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_hooks.md) that are used for similar initialisation

Comment: Like that! I'll take that as answer @Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes itself provides [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) for ad hoc executions. Jobs do not integrate very tightly with existing Pods/Deployments/Statefulsets.

[Helm](https://v3.helm.sh/) is a deployment orchestrator and includes [`pre` and `post` hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/charts_hooks/) that can be used during an `install` or `upgrade`.

The [helm docco provides a Job example](https://helm.sh/docs/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook) run `post-install` via annotations.

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    # This is what defines this resource as a hook. Without this line, the
    # job is considered part of the release.
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
```

If you have more complex requirements you could do the same with a manager or Jobs that query the kubernetes API's to check on cluster state.

#### Helm 3

A warning that helm is moving to v3.x soon where they have rearchitected away a lot of significant problems from v2. If you are just getting started with helm, keep an eye out for the v3 beta. It's only alpha as of 08/2019.