# How to run a spring boot start up method only once in a multi pod environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

I have a method with @postconstruct annotation , that needs to be executed after application start up. My application is hosted in OS with multiple pods. Now the method gets executed every time a pod starts.But I want it to run only once irrespective of number of instances.

Comment: I'm not familiar with openshift but what you will need is some kind of persistence / communication between pods. It can be achieved multiple ways. Eg. if you can mount shared volume to pods you could create file that will mark that method was already executed / beeing executed by some other instance. Using database you could eg. create some record in table or hold a lock on table recod etc. In kubernetes you could access from within spring boot app config map and update it's value (check spring-cloud).

Comment: I know https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock
This library implements required functionality based on shared database. Mutliple database providers along with spring integration are supported.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this would be for each instance to lookup a record in a shared database and for the pod to lock this record while it executes the method.

Once the executing method has completed, it sets the record with a flag to indicate that the init sequence is complete.

This flag can the be used by instances that did not execute the init method to ignore execution.

Alternatively, if you can restructure your codes, you could use other techniques. e.g this link might be useful

[Kubernetes: Tasks that need to be done once per cluster or per statefulset or replicaset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386429/kubernetes-tasks-that-need-to-be-done-once-per-cluster-or-per-statefulset-or-re)